Why are Maxwell's equations true?
Einstein's field equations are true, and have been tested. But the question why they are true has been attempted to be answered by string theory, etc.
Maxwell's equations are also true, but does string theory have anything to say about why?

Physics can describe nature by finding equations that match experimental observations. 'Why' questions of such a nature are indeed metaphysics - which isn't to say that someone on this forum might not have something interesting to say in response to your question.

@MartinC., yes I agree, it must be posed to metaphysics. But a sub-question to this was whether there are any EM counterparts to the investigations of gravity, by string theory.

Well, there is a bit more to the satisfaction of Einstein's field equations. Conceiving them was less an inductive process (i.e., we have a bunch of observations and come up with formulas that best accommodate them); on the contrary, Einstein's thought process was highly deductive. He had the "happy idea" that the equivalence of reference frames should not be restricted to inertial ones. A free-falling observer was also a first-class citizen. He then went on to write the equations describing this idea which made a number of predictions impossible to check at the time (no LIGO ...).

His idea, expressed in these equations, made everything fall in place beautifully. The symmetry and generality is a strong reason to assume that this idea captures some of the essence of nature. (This search for symmetry is recently being criticized because it seems to lead astray; but I think simplification and generality, for example by exploiting symmetry, has a strong innate appeal. Occam and all.)

D.H. Sattinger arxiv.org/abs/1305.6874 derives the Maxwell equations from Hodge theory together with the laws of Gauss and Ampere taken as axioms. The MEs are therefore geometric in nature.

Asking why Maxwell's equations work is a bit like inquiring about a positive trac., "It just does! Ha, Ha.."

Science laymen and beginners always bring up the matter of "why" nature is describable as we find it to be. I suspect that, besides being the dominant mode of inquiry in the human world of intentioned social actors, it connects with a desire for sense of wonder and great vistas of really understanding the universe. And I suspect that desire may be behind your being somewhat satisfied upon hearing about string theory, and now about QED -- they give you hope. Yet consider that any eventual underpinning accounts from those directions will leave you with the same want all over again.

Here's your opportunity to learn something important about your hopeful future vocation, as others have flatly stated: science isn't for that. I encourage you to get the full dose over at Philosophy SE, which is fine with sciency topics, perhaps starting with these: 1 2 3

@ariola I think it's a bit of a crass assumption that I might be a layman, asking reasonable questions of scientists why equations on which we base large portions of our understanding might be true. I find your comment arrogant and unnecessary, and I put it to you that your view gives you hope.

@ariola You say "consider that any eventual underpinning accounts.... will leave you with the same want again." Well I hope they do.

I apologize for rubbing you the wrong way. It's just that I saw you as instatiating a pattern, and I did hedge. Someone taking courses, even PhD level, is presumably still embarking specifically on that field, yes? Anyway, now I'm curious -- what do you think I'm hoping for? (I won't respond lest the thread get out of hand, but I am curious.)

@ariola I think you're hoping for an argument.

@MartinC. I think that's not entirely accurate. Physicists answer "why" questions every time some newer, deeper theory is invented. People used to wonder why the planets follow complex paths around the dome of the sky. Kepler told us that they follow those paths because their orbits in 3D space are ellipses. Newton explained the elliptical orbits in terms of his law of gravitation. Einstein explained gravitation in his general theory of relativity. It may be turtles all the way down, and we may never find the ultimate answer, but physics is always taking steps in the direction of "why."

Define 'true' as a physical concept.

In the context of physics, the concept of "true" refers to the degree of correspondence between a theoretical model or equation and empirical observations or experimental data. A physical theory or equation is considered "true" if it accurately describes and predicts the behaviour of a physical system under a given set of conditions.

Your definition is at best that of 'relatively true' or 'often but not always true'. Not of 'True'. 'True' is a mathematical concept.

@my2cts Exactly. It is impossible to show that any theory is "true" if we use the mathematical meaning of the word "true". Until we can find a way to complete supertasks, we will and will always be limited to testing a finite subset of the infinitely-many cases. Unfortunately, a lot of "laymen" seem to think otherwise.

I don't follow the question (which has been edited so much that the accepted answer no longer answers the question, which is a very bad thing to do). AFAIK, Maxwell's equations were compiled by Maxwell due to experiments showing them to be true? So basically you're asking for a history lesson on experimental electromagnetism from the early-to-mid 1800s.

Unfortunately, there are only so many ways to ask the question, "Why are Maxwell's equations true?" The question has been closed, but also, I've been banned from asking questions until I can edit these ones into a form that might be accepted. If I could, I would delete, but someone has answered my question.

@DanielFBest Do note that deleting questions/answers does not lift the block. It only makes it worse.

Well, if anyone knows a way to edit this question so that it can be opened, I would like that very much.

@Ohm'sLawman I am unable to disagree with you.

I think this question is one of metaphysics and should be directed to philosophers of physics.
When asking a physicist "why are Maxwell's equations true?", one would be met with "because it agrees with observations, experiments and has predictive power".
This would be true with almost all physical theories. No one can satisfactorily explain why, but we seem to know a good deal about how.
And to be a little more accurate, Maxwell's equations are "true" as long as we are talking about macroscopic EM phenomena. The equations break down at the quantum level and so a new construct, namely QED, is sought.
As for your example about general relativity, it is also a more accurate replacement for the classical Newtonian gravitation.

Thank you - that answers my question, especially your reference to QED.

No worries and good luck with your studies.

Even QED breaks down sufficiently microscopically (ie the Landau pole problem), so our current best understanding is still "true up to a point"

@DanielFBest Definitely metaphysical. All pursuit of "why" can continue ad infinity. For scientist the job is to record the facts and construct the simplest possible theories with predictive power and correct description of phenomenology.
